# Adjust speed of trackball mouse need extra help

Tags: mouse, settings

I have just gotten a new trackball mouse, the only problem is it is to sensitive, and it's hard to do precise work. I have searched Google, Software Center, Synaptic Manager, and, several forums. I have tried xset, xinput, xconfig (sp), and creating text files. Nothing is working, does anyone know of any other way of adjusting the speed? It would also be nice if I could change function of a couple of buttons, but this is not something I'm going to spend alot of time on. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
I want it slow when doing precise work, and fast when moving across the screen. I am a complete noob and need someone to explain how to use the tools not just point me to a command line. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Mouse and Touchpad` options. You can find a Icon of same in `/usr/share/applications` directory. Give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

It might help if you provided specific information such as what product you are using, and what commands or values you tried in these tools.

I just bought a **Kensington Expert Mouse** and it was relatively easy to adjust the ball track speed with

```
$xset m 1 10
```

The first number is sensitivity and the second number is a threshold for acceleration to kick in (sorta like turbo). If you set acceleration 0 then is provides gradient acceleration (the faster you move it the faster it zips away). Does xset do anything for you or does it not do enough? try setting really high like 5 and then back down to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I also just got my first trackball and found the sensitivity to be too high. I have a logitech Ergo Mx. I installed `solaar` on ubuntu 21.10 and it allowed me to lower the sensitivity settings.

FYI: I answered "No" to the pop-up (asking me to use plugdev), and then unplugged and re-plugged the USB dongle (when requested by the solaar gui).